# Eclipse CDT debugging: step over not execute line by line

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I debug one C++ code in eclipse, but the control flows are not execute line by line. 
[image]

When I used the step over, the actual control flows(line number) executed were like these:

527
523
527
528
529
...
...
542
545
547
545
547
553
542
553
542
553
542
545
547
545

I am using Cross G++ Compiler, optimization level is None(-O0), debug level is Maximum(-g3).
The debugger is GDB. Anyone encounter the same problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Optimization level is not `-O0`. That parameter is overridden by the `-O2` that comes after it. You can see it in the "All options" text box in the last image. That may (or may not) be why debugger skips lines. You need to figure out where that `-O2` comes from. Check the  "Miscellaneous" section.

Comment: The built-in CDT building has caused me so much grief that I just write my own makefiles. Thankfully they are easy to integrate and as a bonus it actually becomes feasible to compile your code outside the IDE.